# Helm Set Option (--set) | Update Nth key-value of an Array

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

My Config Map Template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.configmap.name }}
binaryData:
  {{- range .Values.configmap.binaryData }}
  {{ .key }}: {{ .value }}
  {{- end }}
```

My `values.yaml` that sets configmap looks like this

```
...
configmap:
    name: foo
    binaryData:
    - key: file1
      value: something_as_base64
    - key: file2
      value: something_as_base64
    - key: file3
      value: something_as_base64
...
```

**What works: I can set ALL the array items**

```
helm upgrade foo_name bar_dir \
--set configmap.binaryData[0].key=file1 --set configmap.binaryData[0].value=xyz \
--set configmap.binaryData[1].key=file2 --set configmap.binaryData[1].value=xyz \
--set configmap.binaryData[N].key=file2 --set configmap.binaryData[N].value=xyz
```

**What does NOT works: Update value of file2 (array[N]), just one item**

```
helm upgrade foo_name bar_dir \
--set configmap.binaryData[1].key=file2 --set configmap.binaryData[1].value=xyz \
```

Error

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: template: foo-helm/templates/configmap.yaml:x:y: executing "foo-helm/templates/configmap.yaml" at <.key>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.key
```

- Is there any syntax to specifically update Nth item of an array?
- Also if my values.yaml has 5 items in array, and I set array[0], then [1-4] are getting truncated off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this helm [issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8320) it seems it's not possible. The workaround is to use map instead or have seprate files with different arrays, please see the [comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8320#issuecomment-644875049).